# svcutil for multiples WSDL and unique XSD file?

Tags: wcf, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I have some (non .Net) web services I want to use from a WCF client.

I have the WSDL file for all this services. Each one reference the same XSD file which defines all types.

I don't know how to deal properly with svcutil.exe in this case.

If I run :

`svcutil.exe WS1.wsdl types.xsd`

It works well.

If I run one of the following, it fails :

`svcutil.exe *.wsdl types.xsd`

`svcutil.exe ws1.wsdl ws2.wsdl types.xsd`

```
svcutil.exe ws1.wsdl types.xsd
svcutil.exe ws2.wsdl types.xsd
```

(this one works for both lines, but when I compile, types are defined multiple times)

```
svcutil.exe /ImportXmlTypes types.xsd
// Compile a VS Project this the types.Cs file
svcutil.exe ws1.wsdl /r:types.dll
```

As each services use the same result types, I do not want to duplicate code (ie I cannot have a "Result" type different for all services).

What are my options ?
I'm struggling with this simple case...

thx in advance

[Edit]On of the probable cause of my problem is that all Services defines the same portName :

```
<service name="service 1">
    <port name="lbWebPort" binding="y:lbWebBinding">
        <soap:address location="xxx"/>
    </port>
</service>
...
<service name="service 2">
    <port name="lbWebPort" binding="y:lbWebBinding">
        <soap:address location="xxx"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally was able to unweb everything using an awful powershell script.

The key idea is to specify a custom namespace for all services.
But as some parts (return types) are shared across all services, I had to extract the types from the XSD and reference it. the process is this one :

1. Download if required the latest wsdl files
2. Set-up path to tools
3. create a cs files from types defined in the xsd files
4. Compile in a temp dll this cs files
5. for each service, use svcutil to create the proxy. Notice the `/r:Temp.dll` required to "share" common types
6. remove the temp.dll file

   ```
       $web = new-object System.Net.WebClient
   $currDir = (get-item WSDefinition).FullName

   if($false) // Set to true if wsdl changed
   {
       $web.DownloadFile("http://urlofmywebservice/majClient/lbWebPort?wsdl","$currDir\CustomerServiceMajClientImpl.wsdl")
       $web.DownloadFile("http://urlofmywebservice/lotClient/lbWebPort?wsdl","$currDir\CustomerServiceLotClientImp.wsdl")
       $web.DownloadFile("http://urlofmywebservice/interlocuteur/lbWebPort?wsdl","$currDir\CustomerServiceInterlocuteursImp.wsdl")
       $web.DownloadFile("http://urlofmywebservice/cdeConf/lbWebPort?wsdl","$currDir\CustomerServiceCdeConfirmationImp.wsdl")
       $web.DownloadFile("http://urlofmywebservice/cdeLignes/lbWebPort?wsdl","$currDir\CustomerServiceCdeLignesImp.wsdl")
       $web.DownloadFile("http://urlofmywebservice/cdeTete/lbWebPort?wsdl","$currDir\CustomerServiceCdeTeteImp.wsdl")
       $web.DownloadFile("http://urlofmywebservice/majDevis/lbWebPort?wsdl","$currDir\CustomerServiceDevisImp.wsdl")
   }

   $svcutil = get-item ((get-item 'Env:\ProgramFiles(x86)').Value + "\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\svcutil.exe")
   $csc = get-item ((get-item 'Env:\SystemRoot').Value + "\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe")

   & $svcutil WSDefinition\CustomerServiceTypes.xsd /importxmltypes /i /dconly /n:"*,MyCustomer.Project.Interfaces.Erp.WebServices.MyCustomer" /o:MyCustomer\Types.cs 

   & $csc /target:library /out:temp.dll MyCustomer\Types.cs

   & $svcutil WSDefinition\CustomerServiceMajClientImpl.wsdl WSDefinition\CustomerServiceTypes.xsd /config:MyCustomerServices.config /mc /a /i /n:"*,MyCustomer.Project.Interfaces.Erp.WebServices.MyCustomer.MajClient"  /o:MyCustomer\MajClient.cs /s /tcv:Version35 /r:temp.dll
   & $svcutil WSDefinition\CustomerServiceLotClientImp.wsdl WSDefinition\CustomerServiceTypes.xsd /mergeconfig /config:MyCustomerServices.config /mc /a /i /n:"*,MyCustomer.Project.Interfaces.Erp.WebServices.MyCustomer.LotClient"  /o:MyCustomer\LotClient.cs /s /tcv:Version35 /r:temp.dll
   & $svcutil WSDefinition\CustomerServiceInterlocuteursImp.wsdl WSDefinition\CustomerServiceTypes.xsd /mergeconfig /config:MyCustomerServices.config /mc /a /i /n:"*,MyCustomer.Project.Interfaces.Erp.WebServices.MyCustomer.Interlocuteurs"  /o:MyCustomer\Interlocuteurs.cs /s /tcv:Version35 /r:temp.dll
   & $svcutil WSDefinition\CustomerServiceCdeConfirmationImp.wsdl WSDefinition\CustomerServiceTypes.xsd /mergeconfig /config:MyCustomerServices.config /mc /a /i /n:"*,MyCustomer.Project.Interfaces.Erp.WebServices.MyCustomer.CdeConfirmation"  /o:MyCustomer\CdeConfirmation.cs /s /tcv:Version35 /r:temp.dll
   & $svcutil WSDefinition\CustomerServiceCdeLignesImp.wsdl WSDefinition\CustomerServiceTypes.xsd /mergeconfig /config:MyCustomerServices.config /mc /a /i /n:"*,MyCustomer.Project.Interfaces.Erp.WebServices.MyCustomer.CdeLignes"  /o:MyCustomer\CdeLignes.cs /s /tcv:Version35 /r:temp.dll
   & $svcutil WSDefinition\CustomerServiceCdeTeteImp.wsdl WSDefinition\CustomerServiceTypes.xsd /mergeconfig /config:MyCustomerServices.config /mc /a /i /n:"*,MyCustomer.Project.Interfaces.Erp.WebServices.MyCustomer.CdeTete"  /o:MyCustomer\CdeTete.cs /s /tcv:Version35 /r:temp.dll
   & $svcutil WSDefinition\CustomerServiceDevisImp.wsdl WSDefinition\CustomerServiceTypes.xsd /mergeconfig /config:MyCustomerServices.config /mc /a /i /n:"*,MyCustomer.Project.Interfaces.Erp.WebServices.MyCustomer.Devis"  /o:MyCustomer\Devis.cs /s /tcv:Version35 /r:temp.dll

   Remove-Item temp.dll
   ```